# Redundant calculation when assigning column values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I want to assign the values of column "var3" to "var2" for a subset of rows in a dataframe. See the following Python code

```
df.loc[df['var1'] == 'x', 'var2'] = df[df['var1'] == 'x']['var3']
```

The selection on var1 happened twice in this statement. Is there a way to avoid this redundant computation?

Comment: I would recommend using `np.where()`

Comment: @rahlf23 how does np.where solve the redundant calculation?

Comment: `np.where()` creates a boolean series (or filter if you will) and then your subsequent arguments specify which values to assign in case of a `True` or `False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you should use `np.where()`:

```
df['var2'] = np.where(df['var1']=='x', df['var3'], df['var2'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pre-calculate your filter ans store it in a variable

```
x_filter = df['var1'] == 'x'
df.loc[x_filter , 'var2'] = df[x_filter]['var3']
```

This way the calculation takes place once

Comment: Thanks! This is a good solution. but  I think @rahlf23 's solution is even better.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious. Both proposed solutions offer improvement, with the `np.where` solution being the fastest. Though none of these differences are problematically large, unless you're doing this operation many times or have an enormous DataFrame.

[image]

---

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def mask_both(df):
    df.loc[df['var1'] == 'x', 'var2'] = df.loc[df['var1'] == 'x', 'var3']
    return df['var2']

def mask_once(df):
    m = df['var1'] == 'x'
    df.loc[m, 'var2'] = df.loc[m, 'var3']
    return df['var2']

def numpy_where(df):
    df['var2'] = np.where(df['var1']=='x', df['var3'], df['var2'])
    return df['var2']

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda N: pd.DataFrame({'var1': np.random.choice(['x', 'y'], N),
                                  'var2': np.random.choice(range(100), N),
                                  'var3': np.random.choice(range(100,200),N)}), 
    kernels=[
        lambda df: mask_both(df),
        lambda df: mask_once(df),
        lambda df: numpy_where(df),
    ],
    labels=['Mask Twice', 'Mask Once', 'Numpy Where'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(2, 23)],
    equality_check=np.allclose,
    xlabel="len(df)"
)
```